# I am trying to retrieve information from my local server and display in Simple listView in android

Tags: java, android, mysql, listview

The problem is with the image, how can i display bitmap image downloaded from server in the listView.I have tried all the approaches available on the internet.I am new to android programming..Please help me..

```
     package com.example.sumit.demoapplication4;

   import android.app.Activity; 
   import android.app.ListActivity;
   import android.app.ProgressDialog;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.graphics.Bitmap;
   import android.graphics.BitmapFactory; 
   import android.os.AsyncTask;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.provider.MediaStore;
   import android.util.Base64;
   import android.util.Log;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.ImageButton;
   import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

   import java.io.BufferedReader;
   import java.io.BufferedWriter;
   import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
   import java.io.InputStream;
   import java.io.InputStreamReader;
   import java.io.OutputStream;
   import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
   import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
   import java.net.URL;
   import java.net.URLEncoder;
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.HashMap;
   import java.util.Objects;
   import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

   public class SearchNovel extends ListActivity {

    SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_novel);
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> feedList=new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
    HashMap<String,Object> map=new HashMap<String,Object>();
    String result=getData();
    if (!result.equals("")) {
        String[] r1=result.split("<br>");
        for(int i=0;i<r1.length;i++){
            String[] r2=r1[i].split(",", 2);
            String title=r2[0].toString().trim();
            String author=r2[1].toString().trim();
            Bitmap bitmap=null;
            try {
               bitmap= new GetImage().execute(title).get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            map=new HashMap<String,Object>();
            String stringImage=getStringImage(bitmap);
            map.put("image",stringImage);
            map.put("title",title);
            map.put("author", author);
            feedList.add(map);
        }
    }
    simpleAdapter=new SimpleAdapter(this,feedList,R.layout.novellist,new String[]{"image","title","author"},new int[]{R.id.icon,R.id.tv1,R.id.tv2});
    setListAdapter(simpleAdapter);



}

private String getStringImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    //resizedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}


private String getData() {
    String data=null;
    class RetrieveData extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog=ProgressDialog.show(SearchNovel.this,"Connecting Server...","Please Wait...",true,true);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String url="http://192.168.43.89/phpmyadmin/shareNovel/NovelList.php";
            try{
                URL u=new URL(url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection=(HttpURLConnection)u.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                InputStream inputStream=httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"UTF-8"));
                String response="";
                String temp="";
                while((temp=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                    response+=temp;

                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return response;
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
    RetrieveData retrieveData=new RetrieveData();
    try{
       data= retrieveData.execute().get();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
return data;
}


private class GetImage extends AsyncTask<String,String,Bitmap> {

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        String title=params[0];
        String url="http://192.168.43.89/phpmyadmin/shareNovel/getImageNovel.php";
        Bitmap image=null;
        try{
            URL url1=new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url1.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("title", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(title, "UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.close();

            image=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());


        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return image;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why are you doing all this by hand? Just use an existing networking library. [Ion for Android](https://github.com/koush/ion) is the simplest to integrate, give that a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Use Picasso, Glide or Volley for retreiving images from Network

Your method will work fine until you scroll. After that it will be all Mayhem as the views will be recycled and everything will be jumbled.

Picasso,Glide and Volley all use background threads on their own, Cache Images so that you dont have to download again and again. They also handle view recycling on their own. Also they will do their best to prevent OutOfMemory Exceptions

I highly recommend using any one. It will save you a lot of time.

Your entire AsyncTask of getting images can be replace in one line with picasso

```
   Picasso.with(context).load(yoururl).placeholder(anylocalimage).into(yourdesiredlistitem);
```

Glide:

https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Picasso:

http://square.github.io/picasso/

Volley:(this is a clone of volley, might be outdated now please check)

https://github.com/johnjohndoe/Volley